# jssor scrolling logo - specify seperate width for each slides

Tags: jquery, scroll, slide, jssor

how can i specify different width for each slides. my logo has different width which starts from 100 to 350 PX.So i want to set different slide width for each slides.

```
    <div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 980px; height:100px;overflow:hidden;">
        <div><img width="100" u="image" alt="android" src="../img/logo/android.jpg" /></div>
        <div><img width="200" u="image" alt="bitly" src="../img/logo/bitly.jpg" /></div>
        <div><img width="300" u="image" alt="blogger" src="../img/logo/blogger.jpg" /></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you remove u="image", you can customize content by yourself.

For example, you set $SlideWidth to 300. Slide 0 contains 2 images, slide 1 contains 1 image and slide 2 contains 2 images.

```
<div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 900px; height:100px;overflow:hidden;">
    <div>
        <img style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100px; height: 100px;" alt="android" src="../img/logo/android.jpg" />
        <img style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 100px; width: 200px; height: 100px;" alt="android" src="../img/logo/android.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <img style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 300px; height: 100px;" alt="android" src="../img/logo/android.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <img style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100px; height: 100px;" alt="android" src="../img/logo/android.jpg" />
        <img style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 100px; width: 100px; height: 100px;" alt="android" src="../img/logo/android.jpg" />
        <img style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 200px; width: 100px; height: 100px;" alt="android" src="../img/logo/android.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```